# Conditions for positive dependence

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint distribution $F_{X,Y}$ and strictly positive density function $f_{X,Y}$. Additionally, let  $x^*$ be the value of $x$ that solves:
$$
\Pr[Y\leq y\mid X=x^*]=1-k
$$
for some constant $k \in [0,1]$.

I would like to know the minimum conditions I should impose on $F$ in order to ensure that $$\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial k}\geq 0$$

It seems quite intuitive that $COV[X,Y]>0$ would do the job, but this is not the case. I found [in the literature](http://kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/decastro/htm/personal/affiliation.pdf) that Affiliation* or Decreasing Inverse Hazard Rate** are sufficient, but I would like to know if there are weaker conditions.

*The pdf $f$ is afﬁliated if $x \leq x'$ and $y \leq y'$ imply $f(x, y')f(x',y)\leq f(x', y')f(x,y)$

** $Y$ is Inverse Hazard Rate Decreasing in $X$ if $\frac{F(y|x)}{f(y|x)}$ is non-increasing in $x$ for all $y$ (where $f(y|x)$ denotes the pdf of $Y$ conditional on $X=x$).

NOTE:
This question had also been posted on the Stats Stackexchange site (link [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64708/conditions-for-positive-dependence)), but was subsequently deleted as it received no comments or answers

Comment: Nothing wrong with posting this here, but there is a stats site in the stackexchange group which might be a better fit.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks. I'll try that. Is it generally OK to post the same question in two forums?

Comment: It's generally NOT OK to do that. You could 1) wait to see whether you get a good answer here, or 2) delete the question here, and post to the other site, or 3) have it on both sites BUT with a note on each site linking to the post on the other site (transparency!). 4) you could (flag it and) ask a moderator to migrate it to the other site.

Comment: Thanks -thought so. Will wait and try one  of the options later on.

Comment: Still waiting? $ $

Comment: @Did: Yes. Also no reply at the Stats Stackexchange site linked above...

Comment: Hence option 3?

Comment: Yes, I followed option 3 (i.e. posted the question on both sites and linked them both). I think I have the answer. I'll share here what I have, and see what other users think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mathematical statistics literature (for example [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2239070)) there is a condition termed Regression Dependence. More specifically, for two real random variables $X$ and $Y$, it is said that *$Y$ is positively regression dependent on $X$* if:
$$
\Pr[Y\leq y |X=x] \quad \text{is non-increasing in }x
$$

(Page 1143, *Some Concepts of Dependence*, E. L. Lehmann. The Annals of Mathematical Statistics, Vol. 37, No. 5 (Oct., 1966), pp. 1137-1153)

This condition *is* precisely the desired property, namely that 
$$
\frac{\partial \Pr[Y\leq y |X=x]}{\partial x}\leq 0
$$

As noted on the reference provided for the question, this condition is weaker than *Affiliation* (and also weaker than *Decreasing Inverse Hazard Rate*)