# Conditions for non-decreasing conditional expectation

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be three real random variables. I would like to know if assuming *Regression Dependence* * , in the sense that $\Pr[Z\leq z |Y=y]$ is non-increasing in $y$, is sufficient or necessary to ensure that $E[Z\;|\;X\geq x,Y=y]$ is non-decreasing in $y$

*The source for terming this condition Regression Dependence, which I also used [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445729/conditions-for-positive-dependence), can be found on [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2239070))